# Install packages from code

Tags: python, package, pip

I want to write some feature in my app, which install python packages from pypi. In my code I want to see, for example, this:

```
import pip
pip.install('some_pgk')
```

What the best way to do this, without using subprocess and etc?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are package dependencies not enough?